# Array Selection

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a two arrays that I am using for an image gallery. I have a navigation at the top with id's for the different galleries I want. I want to make it so that when one of the links is clicked, it loads the corresponding array and displays the images within it. My code looks like this:
HTML:

```
<div id="gallery>
   <div id="slideshow-container">
      <img src="images/someimg.jpg" id="current-img" />
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var gallery1 = ['images/img1.jpg', 'images/img2.jpg', 'images/img3.jpg'] 
var gallery2 = ['images/img4.jpg', 'images/img5.jpg', 'images/img6.jpg']
```

I was using [this](http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/creating-a-jquery-slideshow-from-scratch/) tutorial for making my image slideshow cause I want to stay away from plugins so that I can get a better grasp on how jQuery works. So the rest of my jQuery looks similar:

EDIT: I have changed the click function to what @nullability suggested, but I'm not sure how to pass index to the function. I have tried to enter it where you would pass it in every function but on the if `if (i < index.length - 1){` line i still get an error that index is undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(advanceImage, 4000)

})

//Creates array variable based on what user clicks
$('.nav li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    changeImage(index);
    //alert(gallery);
});

//Creates a current image from array
function currentImage(){
    i = jQuery.inArray($('#current-img').attr('src'), index);
    return i;
}

//Cycles through array
function advanceImage(){
    currentImage();
    if (i < index.length - 1){
        changeImage(i + 1);
    }else{
        changeImage(0)
    }
}

//Change current image to whatever i gives it
function changeImage(i){
$('#current-img').stop().animate({
    opacity: 0,
}, 200, function(){
    $('#current-img').attr('src', index);
    $('#slideshow-container img').load(function(){
        $('#current-img').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
        }, 200)
    })
})
}
```

I can get the images to display and rotate by selecting the array manually like: `gallery[0,0]` or `gallery[0,1]` but I don't know where to start with a click even reading the id of the link clicked and creating a variable that I can put in.

EDIT: I changed it to two separate arrays. Couldn't I have a function like:

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    var gallery = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

and then put gallery into the other code to have it select whatever was clicked?

Comment: any particular reason the array has to be multidimensional?

Comment: @koala_dev It doesn't have to be multidimensional, I just thought that might be easier. I tried doing separate arrays with their own ids that matched the ids of the links, but I still have the problem of not knowing how to start with the click function.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your main issue is with your navigation buttons. You might want to use a `data` property on your links instead of the `id` attribute. For example, if you have the markup:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="button" data-index="1">Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button" data-index="2">Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button" data-index="3">Slide 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can access the `index` data attribute by using [jQuery data functions](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and use it to call your `changeImage` function like this:

```
$('.nav .button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index= $(this).data('index');
    changeImage(index);
});
```

Note that I included `e.preventDefault();` to cancel the default action of clicking an `<a>` tag to avoid any unexpected behavior.

You can have multiple `data` attributes if you need to store additional array indexes. For example, you can use `data-gallery` in addition to `data-index`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying this out. In firebug I'm getting an error that index is not defined. How can I define it for use in the three functions beneath the one you have provided for changing the images?

Comment: You could use a global variable (define it outside of the scope of the click function), but I would suggest instead passing it in the function call.